# Backup photos from Google Plus?

Tags: backup, photos, google-plus

I'm interested in using Google Plus to backup my photos online, but I'm nervous about trusting my backup to only one location.  I'd like a way to automatically download my Google+ photos from the web onto my local computer at home, so I can have an additional copy.  I've seen Google's "Takeout" offering which allows me to download them in bulk (either all at once, or by individual album), but that seems like overkill when all I want are incremental updates. Is there any way to set up a sync solution which will only download new images to my local computer?

Answer (score 1):

Google Picasa did/does offer the ability to sync with your local PC, the instructions are hosted here:

http://yazhuang.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/how-to-automatically-push-android.html

However, recent changes have currently broken this functionality for "instant upload" photos. It is still possible to manually download all the albums using Picasa, and only Instant Upload photo sync appears to be broken. See here for more information:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-plus-discuss/nPOdc1E3TsM

Answer (score 1):

You can try some automated IFTTT recipe with https://ifttt.com/ to avoid manual download

Answer (score 0):

Google Picasa (I'm using version 3.9.0) lets you sync Google+ albums to and from your local computer. On each album in Picasa, there is a Sync to Web' button towards the right, that should sync it to Google+.

You can even share photos to Google+ directly from Picasa, by clicking on the 'Share' button in the albums.